# How to find visit stats for one page on Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia, statistics

How can I find how many people have visited one specific page on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [pageview API](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/?doc) or this [graphical tool](https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/) built on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Pageview_statistics

---

> Pageview stats refers to how often a page is viewed by others. This is
>   not a measure of notability. [Click HERE for the pageview statistics tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Web_statistics_tool)

---

> Page view statistics (or Pageview stats) is a tool available for
>   Wikipedia pages, which allows one to see how many people have visited
>   an article during a given time period.